# Which one is right? "The world is warming" or "The world is heating."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I heard both usages on different TV channels when they mention about global warming, ice melting, etc.

**1-The world is warming.**
**2-The world is heating.**

And this is usually the introduction sentence into the programs. However, I heard the first sentence on bbc and the second sentence on a non-native TV channel (the programs are prepared by non-native speakers).

So, I suspect the sentence 2 might not be correct. Is **"to warm"** and **"to heat"** completeley interchange in this sentence?

The sentence 1 sounds better to me. But I also want to find can we also say "the world is heating" instead of "the world is warming."

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is ideal.

Both "warming" and "heating" are used as verbs that operate on an *object*, for example:

> John is heating his soup.

John is the subject, soup is the object, and it is the *soup* which is actually getting heated.

When you omit an object, it may still be assumed that there is one, for example:

> Soup is warming.

This *can* mean that soup has a 'warming effect' on those that drink it.

So, saying "the earth is warming" is not ideal.

It would be clearer to say:

- The earth is getting warmer.
- The earth is getting hotter.